# Get current platform in a cordova hook

Tags: cordova

I want to know the current platform being used in a cordova hook script.

For example if I run

`cordova build ios`

I want a way to get ios from within an after_prepare hook.

I thought the CORDOVA_PLATFORMS envroinment variable might help but it's inconsistent.  Sometimes I get all platforms in the case of the above command and other times like `cordova platform add android` I just get the new platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `process.env.CORDOVA_PLATFORMS`, it returns a string including all build platforms targets, separated by a comma.

`process.env` contains all information you may need for the build. Dump it for more information.

if you're using `module.export`

```
module.exports = function(ctx) {
    // make sure android platform is part of build
    if (ctx.opts.platforms.indexOf('android') < 0) {
        return;
    }
};
```

Check [Cordova Hooks documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/)

Answer (score 0):

CORDOVA_PLATFORMS does seem the be the sane way to do it.  I don't know why it wasn't working right for me initially.  It's a comma separated list of platforms so `cordova build ios android` would have it set to "ios,android".

Comment: Worth adding a line at the top of your hook:

var platforms    = process.env.CORDOVA_PLATFORMS.split(',');